# Sending source MAC and IP via raw socket

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I'm kind of new with raw sockets and I am trying to follow [this](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/send_an_arbitrary_ethernet_frame_using_an_af_packet_socket_in_c.html) tutorial.
I can see the packet transmitted with wireshark which is great.

But, the source MAC and source IP on that tutorial are missing and explained [here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/get_the_mac_address_of_an_ethernet_interface_in_c_using_siocgifhwaddr.html) and [here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/get_the_ip_address_of_a_network_interface_in_c_using_siocgifaddr.html).

The problem is when I try to copy the source MAC to the known structure:

```
ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifr)   // `fd` and `ifr` already defined
ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFHWADDR,&ifr)

const unsigned char* mac = (unsigned char*)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data;

printf("my MAC address: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",   // prints my mac- works fine
    mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);

memcpy(&req.arp_sha, mac, sizeof(req.arp_sha));  // `req` is already defined
```

When I debug the code, `mac` contains the real MAC address and `req.arp_sha` contains something else.

I also tried to copy this way:

```
req.arp_sha[0] = mac[0];
req.arp_sha[1] = mac[1];
```

**EDIT**
The MAC I'm expecting is: `08:00:27:E7:56:0B`
the MAC I get is: `00:00:0a:00:02:0f`

When I do the same with the IP address, it works great and I can see that on wireshark.

This is the IP code:

```
ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFADDR,&ifr);

struct sockaddr_in* ipaddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_addr;
const char * myIp = inet_ntoa(ipaddr->sin_addr);
printf("my IP address: %s\n", myIp);

memcpy(&req.arp_spa,&ipaddr->sin_addr,sizeof(req.arp_spa));
```

I don't understand if I'm doing something wrong here and I will be happy for guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: What values did you expect? Which values did you perceive?

Comment: I edited my question.. thanks

Comment: Somehow your code is copying an IP address into the MAC address slot, specifically 10.0.2.15. Can you post the full code snippet that is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is req this type?

```
struct ether_arp {
    struct   arphdr ea_hdr;         /* fixed-size header */
    u_int8_t arp_sha[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];   /* sender hardware address */
    u_int8_t arp_spa[4];            /* sender protocol address */
    u_int8_t arp_tha[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];   /* target hardware address */
    u_int8_t arp_tpa[4];            /* target protocol address */
};
```

You are not showing the whole code, are you?

In the first snippet that you say doesn't work, are you calling memcpy immediately after the printf? The only possibility it doesn't work is that mac is a pointer to ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data . Probably the content of sa_data was overwritten when you call

```
memcpy(&req.arp_sha, mac, sizeof(req.arp_sha));
```

Try defining mac as an array and copy the content from ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data to mac.

In the second snippet, it should not work well, even though you say it works. This is not OK:

```
memcpy(&req.arp_spa,&ipaddr->sin_addr,sizeof(req.arp_spa));
```

sin_addr is an unsigned long, which is little endian while req.arp_spa should be big endian. Are you sure it looks correctly in wireshark? Can you print it?

Comment: Actually in this case the `memcpy` for the IP address is correct (at least according to the example code). The SIOCGIFADDR returns the IP address in network byte-order.

Comment: Hi, you were right, the variable `ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data` was overwritten. I used `ifr` variable for both mac and ip addresses. I changed the order of the `memcpy` and it works fine. thank you!

Comment: @userd, can you mark the response if it is correct?